# Prove that the sequence is convergent and find its limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove the sequence:$$y(n) = (y(n-1) + 2y(n-2))/3 \text{ for } n > 2 \text{ and }y(1)<y(2)$$ is convergent and find it's limit.

**My progress so far**

So far, I have been able to prove that that the sequence in monotonically increasing by proving $y(3)>y(1)$, then $y(4)>y(3)$ and I proved the rest by PMI.

If we prove that the sequence is bounded above, by Monotone Convergence theorem, the sequence shall be convergent. I haven't been able to prove it though.

Also, once we prove that the limit exists, how do we find it. Generally, we are able to do so by putting 'limit' on the defined sequence(After proving that the limit exists) and then we'd get a value. However, it isn't working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* For the convergence, prove that $y(n) \le y(2)$ for all $n$.

Comment: Got it, done! However, how do we find the limit of the sequence? One guess I have is that you look at a particular sub-sequence and find the limit of that subsequence.

Comment: @Lelouch, for solving, the only thing that comes to mind is the general theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving, but I'd love to see an ad hoc solution in this case.